# Why are premium cards better?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-chain-of-memories

Premium cards (look sort of like foil cards, I guess) show up every once and a while when you buy a card pack. And there is a "Premium Room" card where you can increase your chances of getting premiums. They are also listed separately in the deck manager. Why should I care about them? The stats looks the same, but are they for some reason better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Premium cards cost fewer points to put in your deck compared to the regular version, so in theory you use them to build a bigger deck.
However, the problem is premium cards ALSO don't get reshuffled after use (just like the first card used in a sleight.). Because of that, I never liked them much.  Your play style may vary.